# How to Customize Axes in gvisBarChart in R's Google Viz package

Tags: r, google-visualization, visualization

I'm trying to figure out how to customize some plot options from `googleVis` in R and a prime example is axis labels in `gvisBarChart`.

Using the reproducible/included dataset `CityPopularity` with `gvisBarChart`:

```
data(CityPopularity)
df <- CityPopularity
Bar <- gvisVarChart(CityPopularity)
plot(Bar)
```

which will give you this:

[image]

Now let's say that you want to add a Y-axis label saying "City Name" at the top of the Y-axis and an X-axis label saying "Mean Popularity Rating" at the end of the X-axis.

In this example you could figure out the values of the axes immediately without those labels, but with non-example use cases the labels can be more important and some audiences are used to seeing such labels.

`?gvisBarChart` tells you to refer to this resource:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#Configuration_Options

After reading that website for a bit, I see tangentially related options like

`list(axisTitlesPosition = "in"))` or 
`list(axisTitlesPosition = "out"))`

but I don't see how to make the axis labels appear or how to manipulate their values. If I could at least get them to appear in the intended location then changing the column names of the data would probably be sufficient to make them say what I want, though being able to manipulate their values independent of the column names would be preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some element of control afforded to the titles:

```
library(googleVis)
data(CityPopularity)
df <- CityPopularity
Bar <- gvisBarChart(CityPopularity, 
                    options = list(hAxes="[{title:'Mean Popularity Rating', titleTextStyle: {color: 'yellow'}}]"
                         , vAxes="[{title:'City Name', titleTextStyle: {color: 'blue'}}]"))
plot(Bar)
```

[image]